# gb4e breaks math subscripts in \caption

Tags: captions, catcodes, linguistics, gb4e

As @egreg notes in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101311/32888) to [Can't compile XeLaTeX document with biblatex and gb4e together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101300/cant-compile-xelatex-document-with-biblatex-and-gb4e-together), the package `gb4e` makes `_` and `^` active to be able to use subscripts and superscripts in ordinary text without having to switch to math mode. Unsurprisingly, this can cause problems, which is why the package `gb4e` has a way of turning this behavior off with `\noautomath`.

Given this, the following MWE does not compile unless `\noautomath` is uncommented.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{gb4e}
%\noautomath

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption[$F_{0}$]{$F_{0}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Although, another way to make the MWE compile while leaving `\noautomath` commented is to change the `\caption` line to something like `\caption[No subscript here]{F$_{0}$}`.

My question is thus: *why* does making `_` active break its usage in `\caption`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `_` as an active character is fragile, so it can't appear in moving arguments.

If you don't want to use `\noautomath`, you have to remember putting `\protect` in front of `_`, when in a moving argument, or use `\sb`:

```
\caption[$F\protect_{0}$]{$F_{0}$}
\caption[$F\sb{0}$]{$F_{0}$}
```

Note that the moving argument is the optional one, in case it's specified.

If the package defined `\automath` with `\DeclareRobustCommand_[1]{...}` instead of `\def_##1{...}` there would be no problem. So this might be a suggestion for the package maintainers.

Another workaround is to `\robustify` the active characters with the help of `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_ \lowercase{\endgroup\robustify~}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`^ \lowercase{\endgroup\robustify~}%
}

\begin{document}

x_y x^y_z

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption[$F_{0}$]{$F_{0}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```