# Biber does not find "too long" Jabref references

Tags: biber, jabref

I'm writing my thesis using MikTeK and Winedt 9 for Windows. I use the documentclass{report} and then I have a "masterfile" with a preamble, where I use the option \input to load specific chapters of the thesis. I use JabRef and Biber to handle the references. I have encountered a curious problem:

Biber is unable to find a specific entry in my .bib file. At first, it seems to be related to the fact that the entry contains a line which is too long in terms of characters. Biber does not "find" the reference and renders the command in the regular boldfaced form. Typically, this happens if there are many different editors of a book, such that the "editor" line in JabRef becomes very long.

Even more curiously, Biber is able to find the same entry if I write a new file such as a regular documentclass{article}. I load the exact same .bib file in the preamble, and I use the exact same key to cite it in the document.

Any ideas?

Here is a probably too verbose MWE:

```
\documentclass[12]{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{layout}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.75in}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{gb4e}


\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\title{XXX}
\author{YYY}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

blablabla \cite{LabelleHirschbuhler2005} NB! 

\end{document}
```

This is the offending entry in the ref.bib file. Its BibTeX source reads like this:

```
@InBook{LabelleHirschbuhler2005,
  chapter =   {Changes in clausal organization and the position of clitics in Old French},
  pages =     {60-71},
  title =     {Grammaticalization and Parametric Change},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  year =      {2005},
  author =    {Marie Labelle and Paul Hirschbühler},
  editor =    {Monserrat, Batllori and Maria-Lluísa, Hernanz and Carme, Picallo and Francesc, Roca},
  address =   {Oxford},
}
```

Comment: Since you problem is bibliography-related and, apparently, is a direct consequence of the contents of the .bib file, it would be helpful if you included a sample .bib file that contains that `X` entry. You can use the `filecontents` package for that.

Comment: Hoiw long is the longest lije in your .bib? I've got an author line that's 395 characters long and biber is happy enough with that.  There's no such thing as a JabRef file, but that doesn't stop JabRef breaking a .bib file (I avoid reference managers because they seems more trouble than they're worth)

Comment: Your MWE contains quite a few things that are highly likely to have no bearing on the issue (`\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`, your redefinitions of footnotes, several unrelated packages). Please try to make your example more minimal by removing packages and code that don't influence the issue at hand. On the other hand you example is not verbose enough, because you have not shown us the offending entries from your `ref.bib`. Please find examples of problematic entries and add them to your question.

Comment: I have a hunch that you may be using too many commas in name fields instead of separating names with `and` (i.e. you type `author = {Emma Sigfridsson, Anne Elk, Humphrey Appleby}` instead of the correct `author = {Emma Sigfridsson and Anne Elk, and Humphrey Appleby}` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864), but I'm just guessing here

Comment: Check your `.blg` file for errors or warnings.

Comment: I'm sorry for being slow, guys, but how do I add the relevant entry from by .bib file for you to see? I see a suggestion mentioning the filecontents package, but I don't get how I actually use it.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 But if you have identified one `.bib` entry you can simply copy and paste it here. Having everything in one document with `filecontents` is a huge plus, but not strictly required to understand what is going on.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question considerably. I read the post on filecontents, but I didn't quite figure it out, so I've tried to add the BibTeX source code from the .bib file, perhaps that helps? In either case, the problem turns out to be more complicated than I thought, because Biber actually finds the relevant entry if I start another document with a different documentclass, even though I load the exact same .bib file and use the same key to \cite. Strange.

Comment: I tested your code, with your offending entry, and I get an error related to the package `gb4e`. After this error, the entry turns out undefined. Commenting this package, it runs as expected. When you say you "start another document with a different documentclass" and it works, is it otherwise the same preamble or a "clean slate" new document?

Comment: This is not a `biblatex` problem. It is an incompatibility of `xyling` and `gb4e`: `\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{xyling}

\begin{document}
Lorem
\end{document}`

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @moewe, yes, I no longer have this problem. I believe the problem was quite simply that the syntax in the author field in JabRef was incorrect (misplaced commas or ANDs or something like that).

Comment: I see. The `.bib` entry in the question was perfectly fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is an incompatibility between `gb4e` and `xyling` or more specifically the `dvips` driver of `xy`. The problem can be reproduced with

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{xyling}

\begin{document}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

Or by replacing `\usepackage{xyling}` with `\usepackage[color,all,dvips]{xy}` (`xyling` internally loads `xy` with those options).

`gb4e` changes the definitions of `^` and `_` so you can use sub- and superscripts outside of math mode as well.
This interferes with `xy`'s `dvips` driver using the `^^`-notation.

You can disable this behaviour with `\noautomath`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{xyling}

\begin{document}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

See also [Can't compile XeLaTeX document with biblatex and gb4e together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101300/35864) and [gb4e breaks math subscripts in \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175301/35864)

If you want to use `_` and `^` without switching to math mode, you can re-enable the function after `\begin{document}` with `\automath`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{xyling}

\begin{document}\automath
Lorem_a
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions, but there is one thing I don't get. I use xyling and gb4e in all my documents and preambles, and I usually don't have a problem. What is it that causes the problem with this one exact entry from my .bib file? Surely, this must somehow be related to the entry as well? @gusbrs, I mean the problem disappears when I use a fresh preamble, I haven't checked if it works with the exact same preamble in a different document, I'll find out and report...

Comment: @EspenJK The interplay between `xyling` and `gb4e` is definitely what cause problems in the MWE you posted. It also causes problems in more minimal examples that don't load `biblatex` at all. Maybe you can recover from these errors if you run in nonstopmode and ignore errors (maybe that happens in your other documents). If I add `\noautomath` after loading `gb4e` your example compiles fine and produces the expected output. If you have another problem tied to a `.bib` entry it is not the entry of your question.

Comment: In fact, I do use \noautomath in my preamble after gb4e, this is part of what I removed when posting the MWE because I thought it was irrelevant to the question. So I use \noautmath after gb4e and it still doesn't work for me. So there is a compability problem between xyling and gb4e, I understand that now. I just don't get why it randomly affects a single entry from the .bib file. That is after all why I posted, that Biber is unable to find the relevant entry from my .bib file. I think my question and or MWE must have been misleading.

Comment: @EspenJK I'm sorry that this does not help you. I'll leave this answer here, though, maybe it can help someone else. It is impossible that *this* exact incompatibility between the two packages causes one particular `.bib` entry to fail, if you use `\noautomath` you should be fine. Is there any chance you can come up with an MWE that really reproduces the exact error you get in your document? Before you do that, check the `.log` and `.blg` files. Maybe the problem is not actually the entry you show, but the one before: If braces or commas are missing that is a possibility.