# Typesetting Japanese in LaTeX errors because of gb4e

Tags: errors, incompatibility, cjk, linguistics, gb4e

I'm trying to include Japanese and English text in the bibliography of LaTeX document while also using the package `gb4e`and no matter what Japanese text I input it comes out in the pdf as "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234". I'm using `CJKutf8` with pdflatex (texlive2014) and have     `wadalab` and `CJK` and the necessary fonts installed. I would use XeLaTeX but I would have to change too much of the earlier code to make it work properly. Any suggestions of why it is not working properly and why `gb4e` causes these problems? I need to keep the `gb4e` package for linguistic inter-linear glossing in the document.

Here is my sample code:

```
%!TeX encoding = UTF-8
%!TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[TS3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex Make sure that ^{super}_{sub}scripts in \texttt{gb4e} work fine.
\end{exe}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{1} Inui, Hideyuki. 2005.
  \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min} バスケト語の文法概観 \end{CJK}
  [A grammatical survey of the Basketo language]. \emph{Cushitic-Omotic Studies} 2004, 1--40.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Here is a brief selection of the error text:

```
! Use of ^ doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ^^c
              0
l.16 ...ui, Hideyuki. 2005. \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
                                                   バスケト語の文法�...

?
```

Comment: I had to move `\begin{center}...\end{center}` before `\begin{thebibliography}` but, other than that, your code compiles fine here (TL 2014 updated yesterday or the day before). Are you sure that your file is actually saved in UTF8 encoding?

Comment: The file is definitely saved in UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Then all I can say is that I cannot reproduce the errors with the code you posted. The only issues are caused by the stuff `\begin{center}...\end{center}` being inside `thebibliography` environment. Once I correct that, it works fine.

Comment: Have you actually tested the code you posted? The line numbers in the errors you posted do not exist in that code so must be from a different document. Test the code you posted and see if you can reproduce the issue. If not, you need a different example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Your MWE also worked fine for me (except for a little complaint about the `\begin{center}...\end{center}`). Based on the gibberish in the errors I'd say it's an encoding problem.

Comment: I think I may have found the error. I tried it with all the packages I have in my actual document and adding the package `gb4e` caused the output error. Where I removed that package it worked fine. Anyone know why `gb4e` would cause that problem?

Comment: Does this help?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101311/24974

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some issue which is not shown in the MWE.

Comment: The new MWE reproduce the problem. The problem is caused by `gb4e` package, which changes the catcodes of `_` and `^`. Note that `CJK`(`CJKutf8`) package heavily use catecode tricks to typesetting Japanese, the problem came as no surprise.

Comment: You can add a `\noautomath` before the bibliography to solve the problem. I would provide a full solution if the question is reopened.

Comment: I edited the question to further explain the problem with gb4e. Hopefully the hold on the question can be removed.

Comment: I've voted to reopen based on the discussion and comments by @LeoLiu but the new MWE still does not reproduce the problem, at least not after `\begin{center}...\end{center}` has been moved outside of the `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: @AdamLiter: Indeed. Since the extra `center` environment is not relevant, I delete it and clean the code anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained in the comment, `gb4e` changes the category codes of character `^` and `_`, which makes `CJK` fail to decode Japanese characters.

As is suggested in the `gb4e` doc, you can use `\noautomath` where you want to disable the special effects of `_` and `^`. Here is the solution.

```
%!TeX encoding = UTF-8
%!TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[TS3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex Make sure that ^{super}_{sub}scripts in \texttt{gb4e} works fine.
\end{exe}

\noautomath % disable catcode changes from gb4e
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{1} Inui, Hideyuki. 2005.
  \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min} バスケト語の文法概観 \end{CJK}
  [A grammatical survey of the Basketo language]. \emph{Cushitic-Omotic Studies} 2004, 1--40.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```