# Using Chinese characters with CJKutf8 package

Tags: cjk, chinese

I am writing my dissertation and I need to type around 15/20 examples in Chinese. I am using the CJKutf8 package but the document crashes each time I have Chinese characters. When I follow the suggestions online, and use the code (and some others) below, everything works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
文章内容。
\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

But, when I use this part only:

```
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
文章内容。
\clearpage\end{CJK*}
```

in my already existing document (which is 50 pages), it doesn't work. I am putting the codes in my preamble here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\begin{document}
\title{Representation and acquisition of kind reference in L2 English}
\author{Yılmaz Köylü}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Genericity}
```

I think it has to do with the preamble. Any ideas? Also, do you think I am doing something wrong with uploading the CJKutf8 package? I am using a Mac, and I would really appreciate if you could help. Thank you!

Comment: It is easy to find out which package is the problem: you only need to comment the packages one by one to find the culprit (which is \usepackage{gb4e}). See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211775/2388 for a solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! As a new latex user, I was so confused, but your solution works perfectly!